# Красивый вывод SQL таблиц в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor, unity3d-ui

я парсю с сайта SQL таблицы в json формате и задался вопросом как можно красиво вывести таблички SQL, чтоб каждая запись соответствовала столбцу и тд. Чтоб можно было скролить таблицу если когда она заполнится, не будет влезать в экран.

Вот парсинг json'а

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GetProd : MonoBehaviour
{
    public JSONObject JO;
    public string GetTypePatch;
    public WWW wwwPeod;

    void Start()
    {
        wwwPeod = new WWW(GetTypePatch);
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (wwwPeod != null && wwwPeod.isDone)
        {
            if (wwwPeod.error == null)
            {
                JO = new JSONObject(wwwPeod.text);
                wwwPeod = null;
            }
            else { print(wwwPeod.error); }
        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        if (JO != null)
        {
            GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect(5, 0, 1000, 1000));
            GUILayout.Label("| Название | Калор. | id Счёта | Дата |");
            foreach (var json in JO.list)
            {
                var data = json.ToDictionary();
                GUILayout.Label(data["product_name"]+"    "+data["product_calories"] + "     " + data["account_id"] + "      " + data["purchase_date"]); // data["поле_sql_нэйм;"]
            }
            GUILayout.EndArea(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Так используй canvas, сделай там scrollview и просто добавляй туда столбцы.

Comment: А какой UI элемент использовать как столбцы?